# Parametro que controla brilho da camera no android

Tags: android, android-camera

Imagino que seja algum parâmetro em Camera.getParameters(), mas não sei bem ao certo pelo o que procurar. Vou ir tentando um por um, mas se alguém souber qual é vai me fazer economizar bastante tempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando esses parâmetros da câmera:

[setWhiteBalance()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setWhiteBalance%28java.lang.String%29)
O valor que esse método recebe pode ser achado em [getWhiteBalance ()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getWhiteBalance())

[setExposureCompensation()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setExposureCompensation%28int%29)
O valor que esse metodo recebe deve ser um valor válido entre [getMinExposureCompensation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getMinExposureCompensation()) (inclusive) e [getMaxExposureCompensation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getMaxExposureCompensation()) (inclusive). Zero significa que não deve ser a exposição não deve ser ajustada.

Comment: Sabe dizer se existe alguma formula para organizar os parâmetros como se fossem um escala? Por que o `WhiteBalance` é do tipo `string`.

Comment: Não entendi, um escala?

Comment: Uma* escala. Criar um parâmetro como se vê ao abrir o aplicativo nativo da Câmera. Nele existe um parâmetro brilho que varia de 1 até 9. Algo para simular isso.

Comment: Olha, eu acho que ali você criar uma classe que da um número para cada string... Exibe o número e faz o depara para chamar o WhiteBalance...